# Does $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^{2/3}) dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, integration

**My Try:**

We substitute $y = x^{2/3}$. Therefore, $x = y^{3/2}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{dy}{y^{1/3}}$

Hence, the integral after substitution is:

$$ \frac{3}{2} \int_0^\infty \sin(y)\sqrt{y} dy$$

Let's look at:

$$\int_0^\infty \left|\sin(y)\sqrt{y} \right| dy  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\left|\sin(y)\right| \sqrt{y} dy \ge \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{n\pi} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\left|\sin(y)\right| dy \\= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n\pi} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sqrt{\sin(y)^2}$$

Comment: @amWhy I think you mean $x = y^{3/2}$, no?

Comment: Yes, @Travis...That's what I mean! Let me grab my coffee!

Comment: Oh man, I had a typo (What a time lose..)

Comment: I think you might want to show that your integral is divergent.

Comment: $x = y^{3/2}$ then $dx = \frac{3}{2}y^{1/2}dy$

Comment: Maybe $$I=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{ix^{2/3}}dx,$$ and then use the error function. Looks divergent.

Comment: After correction, there's no point of splitting the integral. right?

Comment: Moreover, I just need to test if the integral converges or diverges. No need to evaluate it (corrected the title now)

Comment: Your inequality doesn't hold. Sine can be negative.

Comment: Your integral of sin is also wrong. It should be plus or minus 2, depending on $n$.

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin x^k\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges iff $|k|>1$ (in fact as long as $f$ and $f'\to\pm \infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and $f'$ eventually monotone, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the convergence of $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^{2/3}$ at the lower limit $x = 0$ is not a problem. the trouble is at the upper limit $x = \infty$

to handle the upper limit, i will make a change of variable $x = t^{3/2}, dx = 3/2 t^{1/2} dt.$
then 
$\int_0^\infty \sin x^{2/3} dx = \frac{3}{2} \int_0^\infty t^{1/2} \sin t \ dt$

taking the idea from GEdgar's answer
$$ \int t^{1/2} \sin t \ dt  = -t^{1/2}\cos t + \dfrac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}\sin t - \dfrac{1}{4}\int t^{-3/2}\sin t \ dt \tag 1$$

the last two terms are alright at $t = \infty,$ and the first term has no limit at $t = \infty.$

Comment: Oh I see (Easy to show by taking two series)

Answer (score 2):

Maple writes the indefinite integral as
$$
\int \sin(x^{2/3})\,dx = \frac{-3x^{1/3}\cos(x^{2/3})}{2}+
\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}\;C\left(\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2} x^{1/3}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
where $C$ is the Fresnel C function.  The term with the Fresnel function does converge, but the first term oscillates wildly as $x \to \infty$, so the integral diverges.

This suggests an alternate way to do it.  There should be an integration by parts, where we get $\frac{-3x^{1/3}\cos(x^{2/3})}{2}$ plus an integral that can be seen to converge.

Comment: i used your idea in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

By $y = x^{2/3}$, we get $$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^{2/3})dx = \frac{3}{2}\int_0^\infty \sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy$$

Consider the integral over the interval $[2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi]$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} \sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy &= \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy +  \int_{(2n+1)\pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy \\
&=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy + \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y+\pi)\sqrt{y+\pi}dy\\
&=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy - \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\sqrt{y+\pi}dy\\
&=-\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{y} + \sqrt{y+\pi}}dy\\
&\le -\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(y)\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi} + \sqrt{(2n+2)\pi}}dy\\
&=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi} + \sqrt{(2n+2)\pi}}
\end{align}$$

then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} \sin(y)\sqrt{y}dy \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi} + \sqrt{(2n+2)\pi}} =-\infty$$

so this integral does not converge. To be more convinced, see @Kyson's comment below(so this integral oscillates between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$)

Comment: Looks like we can also similarly prove that it's $>+\infty$.

Comment: @Kyson Yes, meanwhile it is sufficient to show that there is a subsequence which does not converge

Comment: Thank you @PetiteEtincelle

Answer (score 2):

$\sin x^{2/3}$ remains above $1/2$ for $x$ between $[(2n+1/6)\pi]^{3/2}$ and $[2n+5/6]^{3/2}$, so the integral rises by more than $\left([2n+5/6]^{3/2}-[2n+1/6]^{3/2}\right)\pi^{3/2}/2$ during that time.
$$[2n+5/6]^{3/2}-[2n+1/6]^{3/2}=\frac{[2n+5/6]^3-[2n+1/6]^3}{[2n+5/6]^{3/2}+[2n+1/6]^{3/2}}\\
>\frac{8n^2}{2[2n+1]^{3/2}}$$
That increases as a function of $n$, so the integral does not converge.

Comment: No difficult transformations, and the argument will work for many different functions, for example $\sin(x^{2/3}) * f (x)$ where f (x) > c > 0 for large x, making any manipulation of the integral impossible.

Answer (score 1):

While typing, I noticed that @GEdgar already noted this, but here it goes anyway.

Integrating by parts, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
\int \sin(x^{2/3})\,dx &=\int -\frac{3}{2}x^{1/3}\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^{2/3})\,dx \\
&= -\frac{3}{2}x^{1/3}\cos(x^{2/3})+\int \frac{1}{2}x^{-2/3}\cos(x^{2/3})\,dx.
\end{align}
$$
Next, show that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} x^{-2/3}\cos(x^{2/3})\,dx
$$
converges.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to look at the problem from a different perspective and to understand exactly why it will **not converge.**

1. The first thing we should know is that if the integral converges the terms must get **smaller** after each "iteration".
2. That means that the function keeps **decreasing** towards zero while going to infinity.
3. If the function is decreasing towards infinity that means that the **derivative of the function and its limit towards infinity** should be negative (the derivative can be zero only if the value of the function has reached zero, because that would mean that the function remains at zero forever thus nothing else is added)

So lets get our hands dirty:

$$ \\ \large
{f(x) = \sin x^{2/3}} \\
\large
\frac {df(x)} {dx} = \cos x^{2/3}  \times \frac {2} {3} {x^{-{1/3}} } = \frac {2 \cos {x^{\frac {2} {3}}}} {3 \sqrt[3] {x}} \\
\large \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {df(x)} {dx} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {2 \cos {x^{\frac {2} {3}}}} {3 \sqrt[3] {x}} = 0 \\
AND \\
\lim_{x\to\infty} {f(x)} = {[-1,+1]}
\\$$
So as you can see the function is not decreasing towards infinity, it is in fact maintaining the same value. And the value of $f(x)$ towards infinity isn't $0$ but is in fact a value in $[-1,+1]$. Thus we can conclude the terms of the function aren't decreasing and the function **isn't converging**.